# How to use transform with a vector using the before and after values

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

So I was trying to find the average of all the values to the left and right of the iterator into a new vector.  I was thinking of something like :

```
transform(begin(vector1)+1,end(vector2)-1, back_inserter           
(vector2),[](vector<int>::iterator n) {return (*(n - 1) + *(n) + *      
(n+1))/3;});
```

Unfortunately this gives me an error about convert argument from 1 'int' 
to std::vector_iterator

I'm declaring the parameter as a vector iterator, but I must be doing something wrong.  I need to do this in either lambda or in using something in functional.  I would like a point in the right direction of how to do this at the very least, since it's a pain to try and search the answer for this.  Maybe if this has been asked before you can teach me what to type in to find an answer like this.

Answer (score 1):

The argument should be the vector's `value_type` (or convertible to it, like const reference), so it should be `int`.

Comment: So how do I go about changing the argument the <int>, but iterating to values before and after the current location?

Comment: I don't think `std::transform` is the right tool for it. Even if you somehow construct the function object to do what you want the result will be much less readable than explicit loop with `for(;;)`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::transform` is rather limited, in that it is designed to
implement a bijection—a simple one-to-one translation.
The function will be called with exactly one argument, the value
currently under the iterator, and must always return exactly one
element.

It is possible for the functional object to have state, but you
have to be careful, since it has value semantics, and can and
will be copied.  You might try something like this, however:

```
class Smoother
{
    std::vector<int>* m_previous;
public:
    Smoother( std::vector<int>& previous )
        : m_previous( previous )
    {
    }

    int operator()( int next )
    {
        int results = std::accumulate( m_previous->begin(), m_previous->end(), next ) / (m_previous->size() + 1);
        m_previous->erase( m_previous->begin() );
        m_previous->push_back( next );
        return retval;
    }
};
```

You then first initialize a vector with the starter values,
something like:

```
std::vector<int> tmp( vector1.begin(), vector1.begin() + 2 );
std::transform( vector1.begin() + 2, vector1.end(), std::back_inserter( vector2 ), Smoother( tmp ) );
```

Obviously, something like `Smoother` could be a template, and you could wrap the whole thing nicely in a function.  (And even more obviously, if you did so, you'd want a bit more error checking.)